# Происхождение слова "том" (книга)

Tags: этимология

В детстве я, в те годы большой поклонник Марка Твена, считал, что Том - это только английское мужское имя, и не понимал, почему так называют книги. А действительно, что это за слово "том" по отношению к книге? И еще, всегда ли оно относится только в одной книге из какого-то собрания (третий том "Войны и мира") или так можно назвать и самостоятельную книгу?
И иллюстрация в тему:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Вот атом – "неделимое", а том – "делимое", "часть".

И про отдельные книги говорят "том".